# Change ImageButton Drawable when state is disabled Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-imagebutton

I want to create a drawable resource to change the image used in an image button when it is disabled.

I have created a drawable resource

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/enabled_image" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/disabled_image" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

And then I am referencing it in the `android:src="@drawable/resource"`. When I call `ImageButton.setEnabled(false)` the button is not clickable but the style doesn't change.

`android:background` is used for other stuff (radius colours etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/disabled_backgroungd"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal_backgroungd" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/backgroungd_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/normal_backgroungd"/> 
</selector>
```

**EDIT** : [**`State List`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize=["true" | "false"]
    android:dither=["true" | "false"]
    android:variablePadding=["true" | "false"] >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_hovered=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_activated=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

**EDIT**:

The order of the items states in the drawable makes a difference.

Comment: The solution works fine. I also found out that the order of the states makes a difference. Can you provide a break down for the order or a link to make sure the cause of the problem is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!ImageButton.isEnabled())
{
     //set the drawable         
}
```

Comment: in the question I am clearly using <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/disabled_background"/>

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future users understand your answer even better.